# How would I parse an array of objects into a main/sub-menu in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm creating a dynamic menu system, however I've hit a small snag. I've got an input method that allows creating main menu items and sub menus, and then when PHP receives the array, I build a set of objects from that.

However, in order to properly populate the menu, I need to take the list of objects and create a list that is ordered correctly, with main and child objects. Each object has a parentID that it belongs to and ID. If it belongs to zero, it's top level.

```
$CountFields = count($_POST["URLLabel"]);

$MenuObjectArray = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < $CountFields; $i++)
{
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->URL_ID = $_POST["URL_ID"][$i];
    $obj->URLLabel = $_POST["URLLabel"][$i];
    $obj->URLLink = $_POST["URLLink"][$i];
    $obj->URLParent = $_POST["URLParent"][$i];
    array_push($MenuObjectArray, $obj);
}
```

What would be the best way to output this array object into a ul/li list that takes the sub menus off the main levels into account?

Comment: You are likely wanting to do a recursive iterator to order the parent and children. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41031756/create-dynamic-menu-array-using-php/41042166#41042166

Comment: That may work - looking at the code now. I also tried to word the question a bit better, if I didn't have sub-menus to worry about I could do a straight foreach. I also don't currently know what kind of storage system this will use.

Answer (score 0):

use foreach to iterate the array of objects.

```
foreach($MenuObjectArray as $obj)
{
    echo '<li>'.$obj->URL_ID.'</li>'
}
```

Comment: I can get that much correct, but the sub menus being in the same array is my stumbling block.

Answer (score 0):

Try using foreach loop:

```
<?php
foreach($MenuObjectArray as $obj) {
?>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $obj->URL_ID?></li>
        <li><?php echo $obj->URLLabel ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $obj->URLLink ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $obj->URLParent ?></li>  
    </ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to stop being fancy and establish a temporary SQL database, along with a regular singular menu entry field, not a whole dynamic table. That will make the whole thing much easier at least for now, and I can convert the storage over to the final type later. Feature creep at it's finest.