# While loop inside another While loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I have been creating a menu with a dropdown menu, but to fully get this dynamicly loaded I use a while inside a while both with different database tables.

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {

    if ($row["menu"] == 'true' and $row["sub"] == 'false'){

        echo "<li><a href=" . $row["link"] . " >" . $row["name"] . "</a></li>" ;

    } else if ($row["menu"] == 'true' and $row["sub"] == 'true'){

        echo "<li class='dropdown'><a href=" . $row["link"] . " class='dropbtn'>" . $row["name"] . "</a>
        <div class='dropdown-content'> "; $sub_c = $row["sub_code"]; echo $sub_c;

            while($sow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1_sub)) {

                if ($sub_c == $sow["sub_parent"]) {
                    echo "<a href=" . $sow["link"] . " >" . $sow["name"] . "</a>";
                }

            }
        echo "</div>
        </li>" ;
    }
}
```

DB:

```
ID| Name:     | Menu  | Sub   | sub_parent | sub_code |
1 | Home      | true  | true  | 1          | 0        |
2 | Welcome   | false | false | 0          | 2        |
3 | Page      | false | false | 0          | 2        |
4 | Settings  | false | false | 0          | 1        |
5 | About     | true  | true  | 2          | 0        |
```

but I can't get it so my secondary dropdown button has a menu.

My queries:

> // SQL-Query "menu" table $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM menu";
>
> // Execute query $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql1);
>
> // SQL-Query "menu" table $sql1_sub = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE
>   sub_parent != 0";
>
> // Execute query $result1_sub = mysqli_query($connect, $sql1_sub);

Visual example of the result:
[Example of Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRMfb.png)

Comment: can you also include queries which specify what result1 and result1_sub are?

Comment: Possibly you are trying to do a recursive menu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41031756/create-dynamic-menu-array-using-php/41042166#41042166  ?