# Building a multidimensional array from database

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get all menu items stored in database as an array (two array types merged in one recursively). Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
// function to push associative array elements recursively
function array_push_assoc($array, $key, $value){
    $array[$key] = $value;
    return $array;
}

$menu_array = $dropdown = $single = array();

// getting menu items (sections)
$get_sections = Db::query("SELECT * FROM `sections` ORDER BY `place` ASC");

if($get_sections){
    foreach($get_sections as $menu_items){  
        $menu_item_id = $menu_items['key_id'];
        // getting sub-sections (in any)
        $get_children = Db::query("SELECT `id_lng`, `title`, `url`, `parent` FROM `sections` WHERE `lng`.`key_id` = `sections`.`id` AND `parent` = '$menu_item_id' AND `key_type` = '1' AND `published`= '1' ORDER BY `place` ASC ");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($get_children) > 0){
            foreach($get_children as $kids){
                // here I need to add all "kids" recursively so it will be like:
                // [Our Services] => Array
                //  (
                //      [Service One] => service-one.php
                //      [Service Two] => service-two.php
                //  )
                $dropdown = array($menu_items['title'] => array($kids['title'] => $kids['url']));
            }
        } else{
            // if there are no "kids" to form a dropdown menu - form an array of this type:
            //  [Single Menu Item 1] => singe-menu-item-1.php

            $single = array_push_assoc($single, $menu_items['title'], $menu_items['url']);
        }
```

**I have two problems:**

1) I have figured out how to push associative array in a loop but not certain how to do that with multidimensional array (`$dropdown`)

2) I know how to merge two arrays but what I need is to join both in a loop one by one -  ideally I would like to get this type of array:

```
[Single Menu Item 1] => singe-menu-item-1.php
[Our Services] => Array
    (
        [Service One] => service-one.php
        [Service Two] => service-two.php
    )
[Single Menu Item 2] => singe-menu-item-2.php
[Single Menu Item 3] => singe-menu-item-3.php

[Contact us] => Array
    (
        [email us] => email.php
        [visit us] => visit.php
        [call us] => call.php
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's only two levels, I should think you would be able to just build using a push for the child loop, something like:

```
<?php
$menu           =   array();
$get_sections   =   Db::query("SELECT * FROM `sections` ORDER BY `place` ASC");

if($get_sections){
    foreach($get_sections as $menu_items){
        $menu_item_id = $menu_items['key_id'];
        $get_children = Db::query("SELECT `id_lng`, `title`, `url`, `parent` FROM `sections` WHERE `lng`.`key_id` = `sections`.`id` AND `parent` = '$menu_item_id' AND `key_type` = '1' AND `published`= '1' ORDER BY `place` ASC ");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($get_children) > 0){
            # Create a base array
            $menu[$menu_items['title']] =   array();
            foreach($get_children as $kids){
                # Push current array with new sets of 
                $menu[$menu_items['title']][$kids['title']] =   $kids['url'];
            }
        } else{
            $menu[$menu_items['title']] =   $menu_items['url'];
        }
    }
}

print_r($menu);
```

I have not tested this, I am just going through it in my head...so keep that in mind.

Comment: Don't worry about not testing it. Most PHP code is untested.

Comment: Rasclatt, mate - damn...so freaking easy... heh... I was thinking in a completely wrong direction...thanks a lot, sire!

Comment: No problem, sometimes it's easy to over-think a problem. I do it all the time! If you want a truly recursive, and more complex, solution here is one that would work, but it takes a little different approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41031756/create-dynamic-menu-array-using-php/41042166#41042166