# Dynamic Menu Through PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, menu

I have to build a dynamic menu through the use of PHP and a MySQL database table. The database table must contain at least the following columns:

link name, link url, link order, link status (live or not).

My question is where do I go from there. I'm not looking for complete code to solve this problem, but wanted to know if anyone would have any pointers or know of any tutorials that could help. I've been looking around for quite some time, but I'm not sure how to tackle the problem with the columns I must use, as I've never utilized MySQL and PHP like this. I'm also very unclear on what the link order column should do.

Below is how I have my database table set up if it provides any insight.

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`link_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`link_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`link_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
`link_status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

I apologize if this is a vague question. Thanks to anyone who can give me any pointers.

Comment: link_order would be like a rank value, so your select should order by that. i take it this is a single menu containing these items?

Comment: Maybe something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41031756/create-dynamic-menu-array-using-php/41042166#41042166

Answer (score 0):

I hope it may be help you. You will get an idea about the logic of dynamically create menu.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
      </head>
      <body>
       <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">   
          <div id="MainMenu">
            <div class="list-group panel">      
            <?php 
            $conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");
            display_children(0, 1);
            function display_children($parent, $level) {    
                    $result = $GLOBALS['conn']->query("SELECT a.id, a.label, a.link, Deriv1.Count FROM `menu` a  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM `menu` GROUP BY parent) Deriv1 ON a.id = Deriv1.parent WHERE a.parent=" . $parent); 
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $random = substr( md5(rand()), 0, 7);
                        if ($row['Count'] > 0) {
                            if($level ==1){// To show root menu which contain Submenu
                                echo "<a href='#".$random."' class='list-group-item list-group-item-success' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#MainMenu'>".$row['label']."</a>";
                                echo "<div class='collapse' id='".$random."'>";
                                display_children($row['id'], $level + 1);
                                echo "</div>";                      
                            }else{ // to show sub menu of rootmenu which also contain submenu
                                echo "<a href='#".$random."' class='list-group-item' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#".$random."'>".$row['label']."<i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i></a>";
                                echo "<div class='collapse list-group-submenu' id='".$random."'>";
                                display_children($row['id'], $level + 1);
                                echo " </div>"; 
                            }           
                        } elseif ($row['Count']==0) { //To show those menu which don't contain submenu. It might be either root menu or leaf menu of sub menu
                            echo "<a href='javascript:;' class='list-group-item'>".$row['label']."</a>";    
                        } else;
                    }
                }
            ?>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>  
      </div>  
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Download link of sql file

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0u93IM3-_XHTWlQLVJsSm9SelU/view?usp=sharing
```